# How can I remove cured epoxy from a bath tub drain?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, clog

I was refinishing my bathtub and got some epoxy in the drain. It's completely clogged. I opened up the wall and took off overflow pipes and I see this flexible coupling with steel clamps but I don't have an access from the below. I'm assuming it's connected to p trap right below it.

I don't have a lot of space to work so anything requires not much of moving would be ideal. I'm not sure if I should just cut it off and see what it's connected to or try to dig out the epoxy. Any clever suggestions? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is going to be connected to a p-trap which is also going to be filled with epoxy and will require removal.

I'd start with the p-trap.  If you remove the p-trap you might be able to just push out the epoxy slug from the fernco.

Comment: How would I remove the p trap? I don't have an access from the below.. it's my neighbor's units so I've been putting that as my last resort

Comment: You'd have to go in from the bottom.